# Using String Array As Object Argument

Tags: c#, arrays, class, arguments

So I have a class that has an argument of a string array. What I want to do is store multiple strings to this array that is part of this class. The code looks something like this:

```
//Class part of it. Class is called "Event"
public class Event
{
   public string[] seats = new string [75];

   public Event(string[] seats)
   {
      this.seats = seats;
   }
}

// the main code that uses "Event" Class

string[] seatnumber = new string[75];
Event show = new Event (seatnumber[]); //And that is where the error comes in.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Remove the brackets from seatnumber when putting it in the Event constructor.

Comment: brackets are part of the type declaration, the construction, and the retrieving of elements. You need to pass the reference variable, which is named by `seatnumber`

Answer (score 3):

Remove the brackets from seatnumber when putting it in the Event constructor.

[For reference.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyfeyz71.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

When you call an array, the variable name does not need the brackets `[]`.

```
Event show = new Event(seatnumber);
```

It the same as you called earlier in your code:

```
this.seats = seats;
```

`seats` is also an array, though you haven't added the `[]` when you called it - so no error.